# MailApp in Google Script won't send email from email address within my business domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to send an email to a number of users from a Google Sheet, triggered by a menu item by the user.

Unfortunately the emails won't send if I run the script from my work email.

I checked the oauthScopes under appsscript.json to be sure that the proper scopes are requested by the script, and they are.

I've also tested the code multiple times in a personal account, and it works. However when I run the code from my work account, the emails won't send. Everything about the code in the two accounts is the same, except for the domain sending the email.

```
function submit() {
//gather admin emails
  var admins = ["someone@example.com"]

  var thisUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl();
  var thisName = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).getOwner().getName();

  MailApp.sendEmail(admins.join(", "), thisName + " has submitted their template for upload", thisUrl)
}
```

As mentioned, the code works fine from a personal account. Any ideas why it isn't running from my work account?

Comment: Sounds like your admin may have configured Restrict Email Delivery.

Comment: After running the code, choose the "View" menu and click "Execution Transcript"  If there is an error, it will appear at the bottom of the log.  To find out who your Administrator is, use the following link:https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208960

Comment: Do you get an error when running your code, or you just do not receive the email? It could also land in your spam folder in case the spam settings are different for your personal and work account.

Comment: Make sure the Gmail service is not disabled for your domain.